# How to locally host a node.js application with nginx on mac?

Tags: node.js, nginx, deployment

I have my client part made with react and hosted locally with nginx. But I couldn't find any tutorial to host my backend (node.js) on another port on the same device.

I don't understand why to use docker or other stuffs. At this moment I just want the backend to be hosted so I can test my API's locally on my other devices as well. Can anyone help me out with a tutorial?

Comment: Did you google 'node.js + nginx'? There are plenty of tutorials out there.

Comment: I have done that. Most of them uses digital ocean, docker. But I dont want to use those now. Just want to run my app.js on a port so I can access my api's from my other devices on a local connection

Comment: Whatever shown on digital ocean will applicable to your local server. The only difference is one with a public-facing ip while your local server has a local IP.

Comment: Take a look at [this tutorial](https://hackernoon.com/a-tutorial-to-deploy-the-nodejs-app-to-nginx-server). You can installed your nginx, node.js on a public server like digital ocean or your local server, it go through the same installation and setup process.